# How to declare a Typescript variable that is going to be set just once but later

Tags: javascript, typescript, variables, constants, readonly

With `const` the value should be set at the time of declaration, with `let` the variable could be changed, I need a Typescript (or javascript) variable that is undefined until is set, and once set, it cannot be changed.

Comment: I'm 99.7% sure you can't.

Comment: Please explain your use case for this. It doesn't make sense for you to want a const value that's assigned later, because that implies you're going to be referencing it before it's initialized. If you're not, just assign the value in the declaration. If you are, you need to explain why

Comment: I need a variable that I may or may not set based on a condition check but I want TS/JS transpiler/language stops me from changing the value later once it is set.

Comment: @Samathingamajig, one possible use case that I've encountered is to avoid extra casting.  Suppose I have `class X { foo: A|B|undefined; }`.  In my code, I might say `let x = new X(); x.foo = new A()`.  A few lines later, I register a callback on x: `callbacks.on("event", ()=>(x.foo as A).method())`.  I know that once `x.foo` is set, it won't change, but TypeScript does not, so I have to have this icky casting in all of my callback code.  (Note: non-callback uses in the same scope correctly observe that `x.foo` was assigned an `A`)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible with a single primitive value, but the logic is easy to implement in JavaScript plus type safety by having a setter method that checks whether the value has already been set, and a getter method to retrieve it.

```
const obj = (() => {
  let val: number;
  return {
    setVal: (newVal: number) => {
      if (val !== undefined) {
        throw new Error('Value has already been set');
      }
      val = newVal;
    },
    getVal: () => {
      if (val === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Value has not been set yet');
      }
      return val;
    }
  };
})();

// will throw an error
const result1 = obj.getVal();

// will return 3
obj.setVal(3);
const result2 = obj.getVal();

// will throw an error if run just after the above
obj.setVal(5);
```

Comment: I am looking for a simple declaration like `readonly myvar` and more importantly compile time not runtime

Answer (score -2):

as I understand you might need something like this, you cannot use const with this, only let and you need to set the initial type otherwise it will inference any by default or you can uses union type like string| number so you could later on set it to both of those types.

```js
let value : string;      // string | number
value = 'newValue as string'
```

Comment: I want TS/JS stops me from changing the value as I explained in the question.